# ggplot throws error `label not found`, while `label` is clearly there

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can plot the labels of the following `df` using `geom_text`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(610, 426, 569, 253), 
  y = c(-226, -276, -364, -185), 
  label = c("accomplishments per week", "hours worked per week", "perceived adequacy of accomplishments", "energy level"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_text(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

However, when trying to use the same plotting mechanism with my real data I get an error:

> `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'label' not found`

***Why* is that and *how* can I solve it?**

---

Here's my real data `df1`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(type = c("var", "var", "var", "var"),
                  id = c(1,2, 4, 7), 
                  x = c(610, 426, 569, 253), y = c(-226, -276, -364, -185), 
                  label = c("accomplishments per week", "hours worked per week",  "perceived adequacy of accomplishments", "energy level"), 
                  from = c(NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
                  to = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_,NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
                  polarity = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
                  group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("type","id", "x", "y", "label", "from", "to", "polarity", "group"),
             row.names = 7:10, class = c("cld", "data.frame")
             )

df

   type id   x    y                                 label from to polarity group
7   var  1 610 -226              accomplishments per week   NA NA     <NA>     1
8   var  2 426 -276                 hours worked per week   NA NA     <NA>     1
9   var  4 569 -364 perceived adequacy of accomplishments   NA NA     <NA>     1
10  var  7 253 -185                          energy level   NA NA     <NA>     1
```

Comment: This is a great question that would be very hard to answer without a reproducible example provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `df1` is of class `cld` and `data.frame` (see second line in the above output of `str`). It would seem that ggplot doesn't like that the object is `cld` first. To go around that, using `as.data.frame` forces `df1` to become `data.frame` class only. You can use `class(df1)` to check it out, or see `str(df1)` output below. Notice the "Classes" line.

```
> str(df1)
Classes ‘cld’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ type    : chr  "var" "var" "var" "var"
 $ id      : num  1 2 4 7
 $ x       : num  610 426 569 253
 $ y       : num  -226 -276 -364 -185
 $ label   : chr  "accomplishments per week" "hours worked per week" "perceived adequacy of accomplishments" "energy level"
 $ from    : num  NA NA NA NA
 $ to      : int  NA NA NA NA
 $ polarity: chr  NA NA NA NA
 $ group   : int  1 1 1 1
```

If you coerce it to `data.frame`, it works fine.

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(df1), aes(x = x, y = y, label = label)) +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

Comment: Please if possible, add a bit more detail to this answer. Because I still don't understand the concept of cld in the data frame. @user322912

Comment: Were you using `multcomp` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/multcomp.pdf)?  It's possible the data.frame you are using inherited the class from a `cld` object from that package.

Comment: @mnm I added some more detail. Please let me know if things are clear now (or not).

Comment: @user322912 thank you for the update. It makes sense to me now.